# Values and links dynamically set in master page code do not reflect in content pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am creating an ASP.net website and as I am not very experienced in the language. I am not sure what is the best way to reflect the values and links I set dynamically in controls from a code behind method to show up on the related content pages as well. For example, look at this simple code :-

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
   <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="logonpnl" Visible="true">
    <asp:TextBox ID="logintxt" runat="server" placeholder="USERNAME"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="passwordtxt" runat="server" placeholder="PASSWORD"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="submitbtn" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="submitbtn_Click" />
   </asp:Panel>
   <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="logoutpnl" Visible="false">
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="usernamelbl"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Button ID="logout" runat="server" Text="Logout" onclick="logout_Click" />
    <a href="testpage.aspx">TEST PAGE</a>
   </asp:Panel>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the code behind for this page:-

```
protected void submitbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(logintxt.Text, false);
    usernamelbl.Text = "USERNAME";
    logoutpnl.Visible = true;
    logonpnl.Visible = false;
    Session["username"] = logintxt.Text;

}
protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Clear();
    Session.Abandon();        
    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
}
```

Now, when I login by adding a random username and clicking login button, I am able to see the logoutpnl correctly. But if I click on the "TEST PAGE" link, the logoutpnl hides and logonpnl is visible again.

I know that because the master page is loading again when I click the "TEST PAGE" link and that why the default are loaded again.

Likewise, if I add any menu links for a control into the same submitbtn_Click method they do not show up in the "TEST PAGE".

Also I added a dummy user name "USERNAME" in logoutpnl through code which does not show up on clicking the "TEST PAGE" link.

There must be a better way to reflect this dynamic data without putting the code in Page_load or Page_init event like this:-

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["username"] != null)
    {
        logoutpnl.Visible = true;
        logonpnl.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Please advice.

I am adding the authentication I added in my web.config file. I don't know if it would help:-

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="Default.aspx" loginUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="AutoDetect"/>
      </authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: press F12 in your browser and check in the network tab why this <a> is not working. Also check in console tab what error it is showing